# How to deal with random.choice in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two lists and the first contains items
L1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'] and the second list contains the probabilities of the users choosing these items, in our case the user can be associated with more than one item.
the list of probabilities is Probabilities = [0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.05, 0.5].
Currently I'm using

`np.random.choice(Product, 2, p=Probabilities)`
but I'm getting a 
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1

Please suggest what should I do to get the desired outputs without changing the probabilities

Comment: I think the error is as clear as it can be. `sum(Probabilities)` must equal to 1. What does "the user can be associated with more than one item" mean?

Comment: Think of it as a recommendation system, we need to recommend the user more than one of the item, the error I understand but is there a way to do that differently

Comment: if I understand you correctly `E` and `F` has the same probability of being selected (0.9). Same with `G` and `H` (0.5). If so, simply scale `Probabilities` so that it sums to 1

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
probs = np.array([0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.05, 0.5])
sum_of_elements = sum(probs)
a = 1/sum_of_elements
probs_scaled = [e*a for e in probs]
```

You should scale your probabilities as [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different) mentioned in comments. Code above does that for you.

New probabilities sum to 1:

```
[0.01851851851851852, 0.03703703703703704, 0.03703703703703704, 0.03703703703703704, 0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333337, 0.01851851851851852, 0.1851851851851852]
```

As you can see the ratios are same.

And here is your desired output of `np.random.choice` as example:

```
np.random.choice(Product, 2, p=probs_scaled)
```

> ['B', 'E']

Comment: You get the right idea but the code can be shortened to `probs_scaled = probs / probs.sum()`. Avoid using loops in numpy as there are usually vectorized functions that do it a lot faster

Comment: Of course it can be shortened but my intent was to demonstrate the whole process of scaling in order to make the User better understand the logic behind it. So they also would  understand why we need it.

Comment: I am glad to help @RohitUpadhyay. I would be glad if you mark my answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this that *usually* works is to use l1 normalization, like with this helper function:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing 

def normalize(raw):
  return preprocessing.normalize([raw], norm='l1').tolist()[0]
```

However, with differing data types the number may add to one as far as sklearn is concerned, yet not quite add to that value so far as numpy is concerned. Your mileage may vary.